# Sitemap is not a constructor while using react-router-sitemap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my React website and I'm using `react-router-sitemap` for the same. Here is my `sitemap-builder.js`:

```
require('babel-register');

//import React from 'react';
// import { render } from 'react-dom';
//import Sitemap from 'react-router-sitemap';

const router = require('./root.js').default;  
const Sitemap = require('./').default;

const filterConfig = {
  isValid: false,
  rules: [
    /\/admin/
  ],
};

( 
new Sitemap(router)
    .filterPaths(filterConfig)
    .build('https://www.ace-up.com')
    .save('./sitemap.xml')
);
```

And my `package.json` has the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:sitemap": "node ./js/sitemap-builder.js"
},
```

So I just run it through my terminal using the command: `npm run build:sitemap` but it gives me the following error:

```
new Sitemap(router)
^

TypeError: Sitemap is not a constructor
```

And I have installed the module also; I can see it in my `package.json`. Why is the error coming up and how can correct it?

Comment: hello did you get any solution for this issue? i am also facing the same!

Comment: hello did you get any solution for this issue? i am also facing the same!

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the Sitemap constructor wrong.

Change this line:

```
const Sitemap = require('./').default;
```

to this:

```
const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;
```

Should work now.